# Why is the parent component able to get Observable type data from Angular service but the parent is unable to pass the data to the child component?

Tags: angular

Parent component displays the data correctly but it is not sending the asynchronously populated data to the child component

I am new to Angular and I am following its documentation from this page: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction I am able to read file details into a parent component asynchronously using an Angular service. When I display the file details from the parent component, I can see that the file was read correctly. When I am passing the data using @Output() variable and receiving it in the child component using @Input, I am getting empty data as if the child component received the Input synchronously but not asynchronously.

Here's the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {inFile} from '../Classes/inFile';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AddFilesService {
  inFileObj = new inFile();
  inFiles:any = [];
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  uploadFiles(event){
    const files = event.target.files;
    for (let i=0; i<= files.length-1 ; i++){
      const file = files[i];
      const fileName = file.name;     
      const reader = new FileReader();
       //ASYNCHRONOUS FILE READ
        reader.onload = () => { 
            this.inFileObj.name = fileName;
            this.inFileObj.size = file.size;                   
        };            
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      }      
      this.inFiles.push(this.inFileObj);    
    return of(this.inFiles);
  } 
}
```

Here's the parent component component that takes a file input and displays file name and file size:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import {AddFilesService} from '../../services/add-files.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-form',
  templateUrl: './input-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-form.component.css']
})
export class InputFormComponent implements OnInit {
  inFiles:any = [];
  @Output() uploadedFileDetails:string;
  constructor(private addFilesService: AddFilesService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  fileUpload(event) : void {
   this.addFilesService.uploadFiles(event).subscribe(
      data => {
        //THIS WORKS
        this.inFiles = data;
        //THIS DOES NOT WORK
        this.uploadedFileDetails = data;
      },
      error =>{
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the parent HTML template:

```
`<input type="file"  (change)="fileUpload($event)" multiple>
 <table>
 <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor = "let inFile of inFiles">
   <td>Name from Parent: {{inFile.name}}</td>
   <td>Size from Parent: {{inFile.size}}</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>`
```

Output from parent component:

`Name from Parent: Test.txt Size from Parent: 57`

Here's the child component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
 selector: 'app-map',
 templateUrl: './map.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./map.component.css'],
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit { 
  @Input() uploadedFileDetails:string;  
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {        
  }
}
```

Here's the child HTML which has no output:

```
 `<table>
  <tbody>
   <tr *ngFor = "let inFile of uploadedFileDetails">
    <td>Name from Child: {{inFile.name}}</td>
    <td>Size from Child: {{inFile.size}}</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>`
```

Comment: where do you put ```<app-map [uploadedFileDetails]="uploadedFileDetails"><app-map>```  in your parent html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

First you don't use `Output()`in the parent components only in the child components to Emit and Event with data for example to the parent data to the child.

And you are missing this line

```
<app-map [uploadedFileDetails]="uploadedFileDetails"><app-map>
```

Where `[uploadedFileDetails]` is your `@Input` variable in the child component

Comment: Thank you. I had this in my code originally but I guess it got accidentally deleted and it bugged me for hours before posting here. I am not sure if I should delete my question?

Comment: @Fight498a, no someone my find you answer here!